# HTML5 - How to work offline with resources that are remote but cached in manifest?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, jquery-mobile, manifest

HTML5 manifest allows to specify absolute links to resources, example:

CACHE MANIFEST

http://www.xerox.com/downloads/usa/en/x/xes_3000Series_Brochure.pdf

Chrome/Safari console log shows that file cached correctly as it's specified in manifest file. But how to get access to this file offline on iOS/Android? I putted link on page exactly as in manifest, absolute URL, when i'm online it's opening, in airplain mode browser opens application, but link to pdf not working, it says that internet connection required, probably it's logical, as link is absolute, but i was hoping that it will check in manifest first.

Maybe there is some way to get access to manifest cached items using javascript and provide link to file as some instance in cache, in another words to make it work like items with relatives urls, which are causes no problems. Or some other workaround. Please point me, am i miss something?

UPDATE: I'm working with jQuery Mobile framework, maybe this would help too, maybe someone has dealed with that, but i didn't find anything helpfull about this question in documentation and official forum.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access this resource directly. AppCached files are only accessible from pages featuring the given manifest in their `<html>` tag.

When you access the PDF, you leave the original page and the browser (correctly) ignores the manifest.

Just an idea, have you tried embedding the PDF in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Have tried today to use <iframe>, <object>, <embed> - it shows up correct on desktop, on iPad and iPhone there is no scrollbars, you can scroll only using two-fingers navigation, it's not acceptable approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have possibility to open pdf in browser and choose different reader for users if they wants. After more testings i come to conclusion that what you said is wrong, althought the first thought was that you are right. Even if you set relative urls in manifest, than when you use it in links as relative too the resulting url become an absolute for browser anyway, considering that app is cached, but i can get direct access to that files. The reason why didn't have problems with relative urls is that it was small-sized images and now i'm dealing with big-sized pdfs. My conclusion is that it's doesn't matter relative or absolute url you are using, you can get access to that files if they are cached. The problem is that iPad and iPhone have cache limit 5Mb, if manifest file is larger than that device requested to you to increase available size fr your app, but it stops caching process completely. So i suppose i need to look on some workaround of partial caching by 5Mb at one part and dynamic manifest. So now it's become a different question. Wow! I thought it would be easier, damn pdfs))